# How can I use the occurrences to calculate the end date of a recurring event

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

Can anyone tell me the best way of calculating the end date of a recurring event from the number of occurrences .

For example: I have an event which has start date as 30/09/2021 (Thursday) and occurs every week days. This event will end after 12 occurrences.
How can i calculate the enddate using java,pleasee provide some examples,Thankyou.

Comment: you can add 12 moths in the given date to calculate end date. for more detils https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances

Comment: provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Show the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Add the number of weeks * 7 days to the date.

For example,
If the date is today and we need to find the date after 12 weeks

`LocalDate.now().plusDays(12 * 7)` // 12 *7 days

Comment: ThankYou ,how to calculate for months and years.

Comment: For month you can use 
`public LocalDate plusMonths(long monthsToAdd)`